# How do I save (bake) a particle simulation?

Tags: animation, particles, baking

I followed this tutorial ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KNO_laPA9s ) to create an audio visualizer, and it's worked great with the audio baking to the curves to affect the particles.

But during the render process Blender has crashed a couple of times. On resume I have to play the animation again to repopulate the particles and create a new animation.

The audio-to-fcurve bake remains intact in the .blend file, but the particle generation and turbulence isn't baked into the blend the way a physics simulation would be. I have BVH caching enabled, but I *guess* that's not persistent since the randomness of the turbulence results in variables between sessions that prevent me from continuing smoothly at the last frame rendered before the crash.

How can I ensure that the data is consistent between renders of the animation?

Comment: BVH caching is for rendering. BVH stands for "Bounding Volume hierarchy". This is basically a "map" of the scene which cycles uses to navigate photons around. It is kind of odd that the particles are behaving differently though.. AFAIK they should be the same unless you changed something.

Comment: You have to have "Hair Dynamics" ticked apparently. Then the cache section appears.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can bake the particles by going to the cache section on the particle emitter. Enable Disk Cache and then Bake All Dynamics. After you do that save your file. The particle cache info will be saved to disk.

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) Don't know why I missed that.
It sure it slow compared to rendering. It will likely take a couple of days to cache this 6000 frame animation.

Comment: @CaseyWagner That's odd... It should be almost the same as playing through the animation as you were before (the only extra time needed is for writing the data to the disk)

Comment: Well, I baked all dynamics, and began rendering the simulation. It went well for three hours but then crashed. (The crash log file contains no information, so isn't relevant) When I opened the Particles properties I chose to load the external cache but it's giving me "No valid data to read!" 
So I'm stuck where I was before. Urk.

Comment: Ah ha! I stopped using the external option, baked the particles directly into the blend and saved it immediately. That allowed it to persist after the last crash. :D

Comment: Most important is that you use disk cache, as if you don't you're most likely going to run out of PC memory and it will crash blender. That happened to me when I tried baking a 100,000 particle animation of 500 frames...

Comment: I also get "no valid data to read" after reopening my file. Somehow blender kills all the cached data when reopening. Is this supposed to happen when using Disk Cache? I was expecting blender to save the cache and read it in case a cache is present...

Comment: Any idea where this setting is for Blender 3.0?