# How to reduce texture sizes in the most efficient way in a complex scene for lower gpu vram usage?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, gpu

After being a blender user for the past 8 years, this is the first time i am producing such a complex scene.

I am working on it for about a month. I have nvidia related errors the last days. I am trying to render with cycles a complex scene animation with my GPU. ( GeForce 730GT) The CUDA errors I receive vary from OUTofMemory to cuCtxSynchronize. Now i am trying to reduce the memory usage of my blend file.

The scene i am trying to render, is an architectural one. Something like a forest in the city, with many trees and grass simulations. The objects related to architecture are simple objects without many subsurf modifiers.

I have a blend file with all the objects linked from other blend files to reduce memory usage. The tutorial i followed is this [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wd3bz62dDLA&list=PL0RtAku-eLdMb4gFVgLgJxgC8BkxpcyMR)

The textures i use are all of them 2048x2048 size. My scene has 22 trees linked from another blend file. The leaves have the same texture size.

So, the scene is ready for rendering, except from the fact that my card and a card of a friend ( 1060GTx) cannot render a single frame.

Is there any way to reduce every texture size of the scene without having to re-map the UVs of each individual object? The scene is splitted into several blend files.

I am very frustrated with the errors i receive. I have to deliver this animation in 10 days from now. I can render it in 3-4 computers but the scene is not rendered.

I would kindly ask for anybody's help or advice on this matter.

Comment: When you say your trees are "instanced", I assume you created them with Alt-D.  Did you also instantiate the individual leaves?  Also, related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51128/file-optimization-duplicate-or-linked-duplicate

Comment: Textures should not be any larger than the size they will be in the final render. If you have an object that will be very large on the screen, then it makes sense that the textures are large. If  you use textures for objects that will only be 100x100 pixels in the background, having 2k images will only result in overhead an will be a waste of your resources. If you have a deadline to meet, consider using a render farm service, that way you can render more efficiently.

Comment: Keep in mind also that is not only the textures that use your vRAM, what else do you have in your scene? How dense is your geometry? are you using subsurf modifiers with large values? Are you using volumetrics? simulations? How large are the final images you are rendering? How many bounces and samples?

Comment: Sorry, maybe i did not described it the right way. I have an assets folder with blend files. Each one of them has for example the trees, the ground etc. The leaves exist in another blend file in a folder called library and is linked to the blend file with the trees. I tried this after watching a tutorial.

Comment: @cegaton Yes. I reduced as much as i could the polygons and the subsurf modifiers. I have simulations of trees and grass. The peak of the memory when rendering is about 1800 mb. but i get an error as i have discribed above. Unfortunately it is difficult for me to pay a renderfarm right now. Is there any way to reduce the texture sizes without re uv-mapping everything?

Comment: Particles will eat up your Memory in no time. To reduce the size of textures load them in an image editing app (krita, photoshop, etc) and reduce the size there, then just replace the image used for the material. There is no need to UV Unwrap again.

Comment: @cegaton Unfortunately with my case i cannot go above 50 samples. So i will render with only 40-50 samples. For lighting i use only an Hdri map.

Comment: @cegaton Oh that's great! My fear was the uv mapping. I have baked the simulations of particles. Do you think that i should save some memory?

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46415/pauses-for-2-minutes-in-between-rendering-animation-frames/46417#46417